# How to send data from php to jquery ajax success handler in case php throws a warning?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send data from PHP to jQuery success handler and later process that data.

I did it simply by php `echo` and then received the echo string in ajax success handler response text. This is not my question.

PHP:

```
function function_name() {
    $Id = $_POST['id'];
    if(/*condition*/){
        echo "yes";
    }
}
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data:{action:'function_name', id:ID},
    url: URL,
    success: function(res) {
        if(res == 'yes'){
            alert(res);
        }
    }
});
```

The above example alerts yes. Until now every thing is perfect.

My question is suppose if PHP throws any warning, the ajax success response text gets filled with two things:

1. The warning string
2. php echo string and hence the js if condition
   fails.

What is the best successful way to send data from php to ajax success handler if there is any warning from php?

Comment: you can add errorhandler on php page ..

Comment: @RohitKumar The warning is already there because of some other function. My ajax call is working and executing the php function properly. So technically my ajax call will never end up in the error handler because its executing the script successfully. But when I alert the success handler response text it prints the warning string as well as the echo string of my function.

Comment: error_handler in php , will take care of any warnings and errors arises ..only you have to pass your required data without warning or for better application design use json to seprate warnings/errors and data..check my answer below

Answer (score 5):

You don't.

If there is an error or a warning on the php side, this should never come down to the response.

In your normal successful case, your server returns a HTTP 200 OK response.

In an error case you should catch the PHP warning and error and match it accordingly to a fitting 400/500 [HTTP error code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

And then you don't handle that case in the `success` method, but in the appropriate error callback.

**Let's start with the JavaScript:**

Here's an example of how I handle that case:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $form.serialize(),
    success: function(xhr) {
        //everything ok
    },
    statusCode: {
        400: function(xhr, data, error) {
            /**
             * Wrong form data, reload form with errors
             */
            ...
        },
        409: function(xhr, data, error) {
            // conflict
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

If you are not interested into telling the error codes apart, you can use [this pattern instead](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/):

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "YOUR ERROR HANDLING" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});
```

**Let's now handle the PHP server side:**

You of course have to adapt your PHP to render correct responses, and I highely recommend for you to use a well-tested solution, e.g. [symfony2 HTTP Kernel component](https://github.com/symfony/http-kernel). This should also replace your echo-driven solution in your success case. You might as well look into microframeworks like [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) that [do the bulk of the HTTP request/response handling already for you](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html) without you having to reinvent the wheel.

I have written a very basic example as an silex application that could like this:

`index.php`:

```
<?php
use Kopernikus\Controller\IndexController;
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app['debug'] = true;

$className = IndexController::class;

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\ServiceControllerServiceProvider());
$app['controller.index'] = $app->share(
    function () use ($app) {
        return new IndexController();
    }
);
$app->post('/', "controller.index:indexAction");

$app->error(
    function (\Exception $e, $code) {
        switch ($code) {
            case 404:
                $message = 'The requested page could not be found.';
                break;
            default:
                $message = $e->getMessage();
        }

        return new JsonResponse(
            [
                'message' => $message,
            ]
        );
    }
);        
$app->run();
```

`src/Kopernikus/Controller/IndexController.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Kopernikus\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException;

/**
 * IndexController
 **/
class IndexController
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->request->get('data');

        if ($data === null) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException('Data parameter required');
        }

        return new JsonResponse(
            [
                'message' => $data,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Requesting the server would now only return a HTTP 200 OK response if everything was fine.

The following examples are using httpie as I tend to forget curl's syntax.

The success case:

```
$ http --form  POST http://localhost:1337 data="hello world"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 14 Oct 2015 15:37:30 GMT
Host: localhost:1337
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.13

{
    "message": "hello world"
}
```

Error cases:

Bad request, parameter missing:

```
$ http --form  POST http://localhost:1337 
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 14 Oct 2015 15:37:00 GMT
Host: localhost:1337
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.13

{
    "message": "Data parameter required"
}
```

Invalid method:

```
$ http --form  GET  http://localhost:1337 data="hello world"
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: POST
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 14 Oct 2015 15:38:40 GMT
Host: localhost:1337
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.13

{
    "message": "No route found for \"GET /\": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)"
}
```

If you want to see it in action, [feel free to check it out on github](https://github.com/k0pernikus/httpSilexExample).

Comment: @danish I have updated the answer to include a basic silex example.

Answer (score 1):

Attach a errror handler , and seprate your warning , errors and response it ..better to do from json , so you can filter both by client side

```
$response=array();
// A user-defined error handler function
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    global $response;
    $err= "<b>Custom error:</b> [$errno] $errstr<br>";
    $err.=  " Error on line $errline in $errfile<br>";
    $response['error']=$response['error'].PHP_EOL.$err;
}

// Set user-defined error handler function
set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");

//now your stuff
function function_name() {
    global $response;
    $Id = $_POST['id'];
    if(/*condition*/){
        $response['data']="yes";
        echo $response['data'];
        //better option
        //echo json_encode($response); **get data and errors sepratly**
    }
}
```

Now if you want to filter errors and data seprately use json_encode and in success of ajax do code something as -

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data:{action:'function_name', id:ID},
    url: URL,
    success: function(res) {
        var response=JSON.parse(res);
        if(response.errors!="")
         { alert('error occured - '+ response.errors);}
        alert("data recived "+  response.data);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing much you can do about that because you do not want kind of error message will be thrown by PHP, best thing to do is use some `if else if...` ladder like

```
if (res == 'yes') {
    alert(res);
} else if (res == 'no') {
    alert('no');
} else {
     alert('error');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So to start with, I would suggest that your php code should never 'throw' an error or warning and that any piece of code that you write should be tested against that. I think you understand that part anyway, but I mentioned this for a casual reader who might arrive here later.

An error or warning should not be a condition that a general js should rely or check or implement a functionality on.
However while developing that ideal code that works, you may want to buffer your output, and by setting an error handler you can mostly likely retrieve the buffered output and send that to js, hopefully as a JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Native PHP Warning, Fatal Error and Notices should never be the end user's concern. Those types of errors indicate that you're using something wrong and you should fix it.

But, if you're talking about throwing exception yourself, in that case you could make a **response** class responsible for mapping your response. Any response to the client should be an instance of this class. Then, you create a new class **exception** that extends the original **exception** to be easily thrown. Add to this class a method that transforms the exception data into **response** data and echo it as JSON.

```
class MyResponse {
     protected $code;
     protected $response;
     protected $isException;
     protected $formFields;

/**
 * Creates a NavResponse object that will be delivered to the browser.
 */
    function __construct($code, $response = null, $field = false, $exception = false) {
        $this->code = $code;
        $this->formField = $field;
        $this->response = $response;
        $this->isException = $exception;
    }
}

class MyException extends Exception {

    function __construct($code, $log = null, $field = null) {
        self::$exceptionThrown = true;
        $this->_code = $code;
        $this->_field = $field;
        if ($log) {
            // store log message.
        }
    }

    public function response() {
        return new MyResponse($this->_code, null, $this->_field, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with the sentintent, yet not with the solution as it is again reinventing the wheel. There are tools out there that handle requests and responses and one should take care for maintainability that they are [PSR-7](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/)-combatible.